# gradle create custom tasks

Tags: gradle

I'm a little bit confused about the correct way to create custom tasks on Gradle. On the tutorial for the [Creation of custom tasks](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-tasks/), they use `tasks.register` like this:

```
def check = tasks.register("check")
def verificationTask = tasks.register("verificationTask") {
    // Configure verificationTask
}
check.configure {
    dependsOn verificationTask
}
```

Instead [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#header) (still official Gradle documentation), they create new tasks that way:

```
task('hello') {
    doLast {
        println "hello"
    }
}

task('copy', type: Copy) {
    from(file('srcDir'))
    into(buildDir)
}
```

and

```
tasks.create('hello') {
    doLast {
        println "hello"
    }
}

tasks.create('copy', Copy) {
    from(file('srcDir'))
    into(buildDir)
}
```

Finally, according to the document https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html, they suggest to move from the second/third case to the first one. Does it mean that the second/third cases are obsolete? If yes, why is Gradle still making massive usage of the old API inside its documentation?
Which variant should a user use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle API has **many** ways to define tasks. There is no "right" or "wrong" way for **application developers** so long as you are *consistent*, but it does matter for **Gradle plugin authors**.

The **Task Configuration Avoidance** doc you linked states (emphasis mine):

> As of Gradle 5.1, we recommend that the configuration avoidance APIs be used **whenever tasks are created by custom plugins**.

So if you are a plugin author, use task configuration avoidance wherever possible

For everyone else (application developers), it doesn't particularly matter, to an extent, so long as your as consistent across your entire application.